# Rails: problem setting expectations on mock model in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to set expectations on a mocked ActiveRecord model. I have created the following example, which should pass based on the documentation I can find.

```
it "should pass given the correct expectations" do
  payment = mock_model(Payment)
  payment.should_receive(:membership_id).with(12)
  payment.membership_id = 12
end
```

It is failing with the error "...Mock 'Payment_1004' received unexpected message :membership_id= with (12)"

I realize I am testing the mocking framework, I am just trying to understand how to setup expectations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're setting the expectation on the wrong method name - `:membership_id` is the "getter", `:membership_id=` is the "setter".  The correct line would be:

```
payment.should_receive(:membership_id=).with(12)
```

Comment: Much thanks, I got stuck on this using `mock_model` on a Mongoid::Document . Turns out I just needed to add `model.should_receive(:write_attribute)` and `model.should_receive(:save)`

Answer (score 1):

Another useful "out" here -- if one doesn't care about the id key -- is to do something like the following:

```
mock_model(Payment,:[]= => nil, :save=> nil)
```

...or maybe just

```
mock_model(Payment,:[]= => nil)
```

Lille